# saving file in Assets folder in Windows 8 App

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I am developing an App for Windows Store.
I have to save a recorded media as "file1.mp3" into the Assets folder without opening the save file prompt. I used the following code

`StorageFile file = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.CreateFileAsync(@"Assets\file1.mp3",Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);`

However the system returns an "access denied" error. The file has to be saved in the Assets  directory only and I do not want to use `FileSavePicker`. Please Help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your package folder is read-only. Use your app data folders from [Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.current.aspx) instead, wherein you'll find a LocalFolder and TemporaryFolder (also RoamingFolder but an mp3 would exceed the 100KB roaming limit). Then you can use either folder's CreateFileAsync.